# How i can display dropbox images in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox-api

I am working on ASP.Net Web Application where I need to fetch images which are in the Dropbox folder.

I tried many ways but could not done. I tried with link of Dropbox images but it also need to change `dl=0` to `raw=1`. So it is getting tough and tough.

```
RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Get
(
    "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/",
    new HttpParameterCollection
    {
        { "path", "FilePath" },
        { "access_token", "AccessToken" }
    }
);
```

The above is also not working for me. When I use Nemiro.OAuth, it gives me error: `"the remote server return error of 400 bad request"`

I have to complete my project but I still have this error?

Comment: First of all I would create a console application to test dropbox sdk to make sure that all the functions that you will be using in your web project are working, I used this guide to get started https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/How-to-Show-image-of-dropbox-in-asp-net-C/td-p/441262 ]

In this code snippet, you're actually trying to call the retired Dropbox API v1 (as evidenced by the `/1/` component). As that is now retired, it will no longer work.

You should instead call [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), and in particular we recommend using [the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet) (as discussed in [our thread in the Dropbox forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/How-to-Show-image-of-dropbox-in-asp-net-C/td-p/441262)) for .NET.